# bpy armature smooth rotation animation

Tags: python, animation, armature, bones

I'm using bpy to control a blender armature using Python. I am able to get the armature to rotate properly, but it is a very jumpy rotation, there is no smooth animation of any sort. Is there anyways to create a smooth animation in bpy? This is my code:

```
 poseTable = [
        ('finger1joint1', 'X', -5),
        ('finger1joint1', 'X', -5),
        ('finger1joint1', 'X', -5),
        ('finger1joint1', 'X', -5),
    ]

for (bname, axis, angle) in poseTable:
    pbone = ob.pose.bones[bname]
    # Set rotation mode to Euler XYZ, easier to understand
    # than default quaternions
    pbone.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
    # Documentation bug: Euler.rotate(angle,axis):
    # axis in ['x','y','z'] and not ['X','Y','Z']
    pbone.rotation_euler.rotate_axis(axis, math.radians(angle))
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Comment: add them as keyframes to get the smooth interpolation

Comment: Hey Chebou, how exactly would I do that, say I was rotating by 45 degrees. How would I translate that into using keyframes?

Comment: take a look at this [adding keyframes through python](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_63_5/info_quickstart.html#animation)

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: No, I added the key frames but the animation is still jumpy. My other problem is that I need to be able to monitor a file or a socket and when new information comes in, rotate the angle of the armature. I don't know how to get this constant monitoring behaviour

Comment: i'll try the keyframe thing later, but for the constant monitoring did you try bpy.app.handlers(frame_change_pre)?